# transformation_ctx value is not stored for the incremental purpose in the glue job temp dir

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to load `incremental` data from `Redshift` to the `s3`. I have set up `redshift_temp_dir` and `temp dir` for `glue` jobs(using glue console).

Below is my code:

```
my_conn_options = {
            "url": "",
            "dbtable": "",
            "user": "",
            "password": "",
            "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://madl-temp/redshift_temp/"
        }
        
data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type="redshift",
                                                         connection_options=my_conn_options,
                                                         transformation_ctx=table_name,
                                                         additional_options={
                                                             "jobBookmarkKeys": ["timestamp"],
                                                             "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder": "asc"}).toDF()

log.info(str(data.count()))
```

Where `date_col` is a timestamp column in redshift. I have also used `job.init(`) and `job.commit()` in my code and after every run I am getting the complete data load count and not the newly added rows in my redshift table.
As per the documentation below I can use Redshift as my JDBC source for the incremental purpose too.

[image]

I am not able to see any `metadata` for `transformation_ctx` in the glue temp directory. So, what could be the reason for my problem? Or am I missing something?

Comment: you need to enable bookmarking on your job and pass a column while reading which uniquely identify the rows so that it can read from the last processed row. refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Comment: I have enabled the job bookmark option and also I have modified my code as per the AWS blogs but still, it is loading the entire dataset every time. Please refer the updated code in my post

Comment: Now, after trying multiple ways I think job bookmarks loads the incremental data only when `S3` is acting as a source.

Comment: it does support jdbc sources but with conditions. Please check the above link for conditions

Comment: Yeah, even my attached image in the post says the same. The only thing I haven't tried so far is `jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder`. Let me try it!

Comment: If the key is not unique then it will not work. I believe the column date_col that you are using does not have unique values across the table

Comment: No, it is a timestamp when it was inserted. But if multiple records was inserted at the same timestamp then definitely it will have the same value.

Comment: I tried and the last option didn't work as well. I have edited my post again.

Comment: Any solution to my problem? Any help is much appreciated. Or this won't work with Redshift?

Comment: Your date_col passed while reading into dynamic frame has duplicates and it won't work.try passing a column which has only unique values